# Smooth out a concave edge

Tags: edges, bevel

Hey guys beginner user here.

I'm trying to model a skateboard to get the hand of using blender and I was able to get the basic shape down except I have an edge that is too sharp. I tried multiple technics but I was unable to get it to work.

This is what I have:

[image]
[image]

What I'm trying to smoothen out is the hard-line where the body meets the tail. make it look like a more round edge.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally a result of the complexity of working with the subdivision surface modifier. The closer together your edge loops are, the more of a "crease" you will get.

To solve this, I would recommend individually selecting the edge loops on each side of the center edge loop where the crease is and edge sliding (double tap G) them away from each other until the "crease" is smoothed out. As an aside, you should consider if those three edge loops are even needed: is it possible to get away with only one?

Please edit your post to share your blend file too - it would really help!

You can use this site to share blend files: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem. I also got rid of the other two edge loops, it was initially one but since I couldn't get rid of the crease I added them to try other methods out.